# How does LocationTest choose its "AutomaticTest"?

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics, distributions, implementation-details

Is there a way of determining how `LocationTest` chooses its `"AutomaticTest"`?

Sometimes it's clear from the `VerifyTestAssumptions` option

```
sample = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[7];RandomVariate[SkewNormalDistribution@2, 10]];

{LocationTest[sample, Automatic, "AutomaticTest", VerifyTestAssumptions ->{"Normality"}],
LocationTest[sample, Automatic, "AutomaticTest", VerifyTestAssumptions -> "Normality" -> True]}
```

> {SignedRank, T}

other times less so

```
{LocationTest[sample, Automatic, "AutomaticTest", SignificanceLevel -> 0.05],
 LocationTest[sample, Automatic, "AutomaticTest", SignificanceLevel -> 0.0005]}
```

> {SignedRank, T}

( i.e. how can the level of the apriori-decided "burden of proof" affect the resulting sampling distribution? )

**Update 1:**

Following on from the comments - Perhaps the setting for the significance level is somehow being inherited in checks for normality i.e.

```
{DistributionFitTest[sample, NormalDistribution[],"ShortTestConclusion", SignificanceLevel -> 0.05], 
DistributionFitTest[sample, NormalDistribution[],"ShortTestConclusion", SignificanceLevel -> 0.0005],
DistributionFitTest[sample, NormalDistribution[], "PValue"]}
```

> {Reject,Do not reject,0.00836514}

The critical point is not around the previous p-value instead appearing just after 0.03

```
Plot[If[LocationTest[sample, Automatic, "AutomaticTest", SignificanceLevel -> x] === "T", 1, 0], {x, 0.01, 0.05}]
```

[image]

If so, perhaps some sort of Bonferroni correction is taking place?

**Update 2:**

From the answer from Andy Ross, the relevant test is not

```
 DistributionFitTest[sample, NormalDistribution[]]

(*0.00836514*)
```

but rather

```
 DistributionFitTest[sample]

(*0.0307822*)
```

indicating that indeed this significance level is being filtered down. This doesn't however, provide a systematic answer to determining *how* this choice is made in general. In this case, the logic used by `LocationTest` can be deduced because it is a standard example but applying NHST can be a bit of an art that depends heavily on circumstance for its ultimate interpretation. Hence, having a black box for this logic seems limiting in perhaps a far more consequential way than say for other "more deterministic" and clear-cut algorithms.

Also, what is the rationale behind this inheritance? - in NHST machinery, the significance level has a specific meaning in relation to Type 1/Type 2 errors, power, experimental context etc with the theory being predicated on a test's conditions being apriori satisfied *without* concession to their own uncertainty (e.g. despite a p-value being returned, is an error message for a failed test of normality in say TTest invocations counted as a false negative/positive in defining a Type 1/Type2 error?).

```
sample2 = {6.1, -8.4, 1, 2, 0.75, 2.9, 3.5, 5.1, 1.8, 3.6, 7., 3, 9.4,
    7.5, -6};
TTest@sample2

(* TTest::nortst: At least one of the p-values in {0.0903246}, resulting from a test for
normality, is below 0.05`. The tests in {T} require that the data is normally distributed. >> *)

(* 0.0498525 *)
```

The warning above doesn't seem to fit since 0.0903246 is not below 0.05 but explicitly set the significance level to the default 5% however, and the warning message disappears?

```
TTest[sample2, SignificanceLevel -> 0.05]

(* 0.0498525 *)
```

At any rate, in general it is quite conceivable that a different significance level for the overarching test might be needed in comparison with the significant level required for an apriori test checking the data's normality, symmetry, heterogeneity etc (n.b. also how are all these combined from the initial setting?)

**Update 3:**
To be a little more systematic: Define a function `ShowSignificanceLevelThresholds` to show those significant levels at which `LocationTest` changes its choice of `"AutomaticTest"` (the `"HighlightAutomaticTest"` option highlights this choice - both are defined at the post's end).

```
LocationTest[sample2, Automatic, {"TestDataTable", All},"HighlightAutomaticTest" -> True]
// ShowSignificanceLevelThresholds
```

[image]

As deduced, the first transition appears due to the Koglomorov-Smirnof test of normality and its p-value of 0.09.

```
DistributionFitTest[sample2, Automatic, {"TestDataTable", All}, 
"HighlightAutomaticTest" -> True]
```

[image]

The second transition at a significance level 0.604 would appear to involve the violation of a symmetry assumption (observable by manual setting the `"Symmetry"` and `"Normality"` options to in the `"VerifyTestAssumption"` option) so that a related question becomes what Test is used by default to test for symmetry?

While a high significance level of 0.604 is unlikely to have much practical significance in this particular case, this may not apply more generally. Again, the unknown effects of passing a significance level down to diagnostic tests is not straightforward and suggests caution in applying `LocationTest` and its ilk together with scope for further improvements (discussed in more detail [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46635/how-does-locationtest-two-samples-select-its-automatictest)).

```
(*Needs to be evaluated twice*)
ALocationTest[sample_, x_, {tableType_, All}, y___ : OptionsPattern] /;
TrueQ@("HighlightAutomaticTest" /. {y}) := 
With[{\[ScriptCapitalH]2 = 
 LocationTest[sample, x, "HypothesisTestData", 
  FilterRules[{y}, Except["HighlightAutomaticTest"]]]}, 
Module[{AT = \[ScriptCapitalH]2["AutomaticTest"], 
 AllTests = \[ScriptCapitalH]2["AllTests"], 
 TableDataType = StringDrop[tableType, -5],(*Dropping "Table"*)
 pos, Headers, grid, TableData}, 
TableData = \[ScriptCapitalH]2[{TableDataType, All}];
pos = 1 + Position[AllTests, AT][[1, 1]];
Headers = 
 Switch[TableDataType, "TestData", {"  ", "Statistic", "P-Value"},
   "TestStatistic", {"  ", "Statistic"}, 
  "PValue", {"  ", "P-Value"}];
Grid[{Headers, 
   Sequence @@ 
    MapThread[
     Flatten[Join[{#1}, {#2}]] &, {AllTests, TableData}]}, 
  Alignment -> Left, 
  Background -> {Automatic, pos -> GrayLevel@0.9}, 
  Dividers -> {2 -> True, 2 -> True}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel@.7]] // Text]];

Unprotect@LocationTest;
PrependTo[DownValues@LocationTest, 
DownValues[ALocationTest] /. ALocationTest -> LocationTest];
Protect@LocationTest;

AVarianceTest[sample_, x_, {tableType_, All}, y___ : OptionsPattern] /;
TrueQ@("HighlightAutomaticTest" /. {y}) := 
With[{\[ScriptCapitalH]2 = 
 VarianceTest[sample, x, "HypothesisTestData", 
  FilterRules[{y}, Except["HighlightAutomaticTest"]]]}, 
Module[{AT = \[ScriptCapitalH]2["AutomaticTest"], 
 AllTests = \[ScriptCapitalH]2["AllTests"], 
 TableDataType = StringDrop[tableType, -5],(*Dropping "Table"*)
 pos, Headers, grid, TableData}, 
TableData = \[ScriptCapitalH]2[{TableDataType, All}];
pos = 1 + Position[AllTests, AT][[1, 1]];
Headers = 
 Switch[TableDataType, "TestData", {"  ", "Statistic", "P-Value"},
   "TestStatistic", {"  ", "Statistic"}, 
  "PValue", {"  ", "P-Value"}];
Grid[{Headers, 
   Sequence @@ 
    MapThread[
     Flatten[Join[{#1}, {#2}]] &, {AllTests, TableData}]}, 
  Alignment -> Left, 
  Background -> {Automatic, pos -> GrayLevel@0.9}, 
  Dividers -> {2 -> True, 2 -> True}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel@.7]] // Text]];

Unprotect@VarianceTest;
PrependTo[DownValues@VarianceTest, 
DownValues[AVarianceTest] /. AVarianceTest -> VarianceTest];
Protect@VarianceTest;

ADistributionFitTest[sample_, x_, {tableType_, All}, 
y___ : OptionsPattern] /; 
TrueQ@("HighlightAutomaticTest" /. {y}) :=

With[{\[ScriptCapitalH]2 = 
 DistributionFitTest[sample, x, "HypothesisTestData", 
  FilterRules[{y}, Except["HighlightAutomaticTest"]]]},
Module[
{AT = \[ScriptCapitalH]2["AutomaticTest"],
 AllTests = \[ScriptCapitalH]2["AllTests"],
 TableDataType = StringDrop[tableType, -5],
 (* Dropping "Table" *)
 pos, Headers, grid, TableData
 },
TableData = \[ScriptCapitalH]2[{TableDataType, All}];
pos = 1 + Position[AllTests, AT][[1, 1]];
Headers = Switch[TableDataType,
  "TestData", {"  ", "Statistic", "P-Value"},
  "TestStatistic", {"  ", "Statistic"},
  "PValue", {"  ", "P-Value"}
  ];
Grid[{
   Headers,
   Sequence @@ 
    MapThread[Flatten[Join[{#1}, {#2}]] &, {AllTests, TableData}]
   }, Alignment -> Left, 
  Background -> {Automatic, pos -> GrayLevel@0.9}, 
  Dividers -> {2 -> True, 2 -> True}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel@.7]] // Text
]];

Unprotect@DistributionFitTest;
PrependTo[DownValues@DistributionFitTest, 
DownValues[ADistributionFitTest] /. 
ADistributionFitTest -> DistributionFitTest];
Protect@DistributionFitTest;


SetAttributes[SignificanceLevelThresholds, HoldFirst];
SetAttributes[ShowSignificanceLevelThresholds, HoldFirst];

 SignificanceLevelThresholds[test_[A__]] := 
 With[{firstTest = test[A, SignificanceLevel -> 0.0001]}, 
 Last /@ 
 Split[Table[{i, test[A, SignificanceLevel -> i]}, {i, 0.001, .999,
    0.001}], Last@#1 === Last@#2 &]];

ShowSignificanceLevelThresholds[test_[A__]] := 
Module[{NForm}, 
NForm[n_] := If[MemberQ[{0, 1}, n], n, NumberForm[n, {4, 3}]];
With[{SLT = SignificanceLevelThresholds[test[A]]}, 
With[{intervals = 
  StringForm[
     "`1` < \[FilledSquare] < `2`", #[[1]] // NForm, #[[2]] // 
      NForm] & /@ 
   Partition[Prepend[SLT[[All, 1]] /. .999 -> 1, 0], 2, 1], 
 TestOutputs = SLT[[All, 2]]}, 
Grid[{{HoldForm@
     test[A, SignificanceLevel -> \[SelectionPlaceholder]] // 
    Style[#, Bold] &, 
   Sequence @@ ConstantArray[SpanFromLeft, Length@SLT - 1]}, 
  intervals, TestOutputs}, 
 Spacings -> {2, {1 -> 2, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 1}}, 
 Background -> {None, 2 -> LightBlue}, 
 ItemStyle -> {None, 2 -> Directive[15]}, 
 Dividers -> {{True, True, 3, 4}, {True, True, False, True}}, 
 ItemSize -> 16, Frame -> True]]]]
```

Comment: Wrt to your last example: This is at least partly documented in [the last example of the Possible Issues section](http://wolfram.com/xid/0h2peojsme-85atl) of the `LocationTest` doc page. The significance level has an impact on internal diagnosis tests (in this case a test on equal variance) which changes the degrees of freedom.

Comment: Yes, and curiously LocationTest[sample, Automatic, "AutomaticTest", 
   SignificanceLevel -> 0.05, 
   VerifyTestAssumptions -> #] & /@ {"Normality", "EqualVariance", 
  "EqualVariance" -> True, "EqualVariance" -> False} gives {"SignedRank", "T", "T", "T"} but in this example there is only one sample so I'm not sure what variances are being checked for equality?

Comment: In the first case you are saying "check for normality" in the remaining examples you are saying "ignore normality and just check for equal variances". Since there is only one sample the equal variances test has no impact on the test that is chosen.

Comment: With that in mind, there should probably be a message saying the equal variance test is being ignored...

Comment: Yes but one might have expected that there is an outcome of the variance check that results in "SignedRank" still being chosen. I.e. otherwise we are moving into Heisenberg territory in which the mere process of "checking" equal variances becomes pivotal (given NHST's dichotomous tradition of being either true or false). At any rate, I agree this is a red herring since there is only one sample. Perhaps what is going on ... see addition to question

Comment: This question is tagged with `bugs`, but it's a very long post and after a quick skim it's not clear where/what the bug is.  Can you clarify and give a summary of the bug at the top, for the benefit of other readers?

Comment: @Szabolcs I guess the overarching "bug" relates to the point of the question - the black box nature of `LocationTest` (together with the use of subsidiary tests to decide assumptions) but the bug tagging in the conventional sense stemmed from one of the examples -  `sample2 = {6.1, -8.4, 1, 2, 0.75, 2.9, 3.5, 5.1, 1.8, 3.6, 7., 3, 9.4, 7.5, -6};
TTest@sample2` where the output states that "`{0.0903246}`, resulting from a test for normality, is below `0.05`" when clearly `0.0903246 > 0.05`. Also the following command where the error message is not generated despite the same significance ...

Comment: level being used suggests another bug although it is difficult to say categorically because of the opaqueness in how this significance level is filtered down. This behaviour remains the same in V10. Perhaps it would be better to untag this post's bug tag and instead tag another post with the specific bug? (if justified and worth posting separately by anyone) –

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a single sample the test for normality is the deciding factor in what test to choose.

The key here is that `DistributionFitTest` is not testing against `NormalDistribution[0,1]` by default.  It is testing against the family of normal distributions.

```
DistributionFitTest[sample]

(*0.0307822*)

DistributionFitTest[sample, NormalDistribution[]]

(*0.00836514*)
```

The T test is chosen until the significance level is greater than the p-value for the test for normality.

Comment: Yes I [similarly](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/what-default-theoretical-distribution-does-mathematica-use-in-pearsonchisquarete/4287) overlooked this point and it does seem to confirm that this significance level is being inherited from the original invocation.