# What is the meaning of Automatic in goodness of fit test?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I can't find what is the distribution corresponding to the default option in:

```
DistributionFitTest[data, Automatic, "HypothesisTestData"];
```

Is it N(0,1), uniform?

Comment: Does [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40499/12) answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

By default `DistributionFitTest` attempts to test fit against the family of normal distributions.  To test if the data is standard normal (i.e. N(0,1)) you would use.

```
DistributionFitTest[data, NormalDistribution[]]
```

There are examples that show this to be the case in the Properties & Relations section of the documentation for `DistributionFitTest`.

Comment: When you have time, could you take a look whether [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47722/12) looks reasonable?  I have an actual [practical need](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15483967#15483967) for this.  My distribution looks like a histogram, but it comes from [probabilistic bisection (see pages 13-15)](http://people.orie.cornell.edu/shane/theses/ThesisRolfWaeber.pdf) and not from counting data points.

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't see anything wrong with your approach. I don't have access to the source so I can't promise that the Infinity is safe across the board. You know the typical caveat about undocumented internals being subject to change.

Comment: Suggest this may be a Beta distribution, not a normal one. Before testing the fit to any distribution, you should identify which one it is. I do this 100 times and find the best one looping FD = FindDistribution[data, 5, "BIC", "RandomSeed" -> foundi - 1, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"] in Mathematica 10.3 The functionality may be different in other versions.

Comment: @Andy Ross No, first of all ND is bounded on $(-\infty ,\infty )$ and your results as well as BD are bounded on $(0,1)$. Such that you data may be BD. Best to let *Mathematica* tell you which distribution it most likely is see [FindDistribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDistribution.html). That will go through a lot of distributions and select the best ones.

Comment: @Andy Ross Sorry, my bad. The results pertain to [probabilistic bisection (see pages 13-15)](https://people.orie.cornell.edu/shane/theses/ThesisRolfWaeber.pdf) and Szabolcs's comment.

Comment: @Szabolcs Please see comments above. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Carl Sorry, I'm a bit lost here and I don't see the connection of your comments and probabilistic bisection, maybe I'm missing context ... perhaps you can join the chatroom?

Comment: @Szabolcs please explain how I can do that. So far, all I know is how to agree to an automatic link to transfer a longer conversation to a chat room.